How do I get an IShellItemFilter object?
I need an IShellItemFilter object to call GetEnumFlagsForItem on item on it so I can find out hat flags to use to include AppData in EnomObjects of IShellFolder.
However, I can't seem to cast anything to IShellItemFilter.
I've tried casting an IShellItem2, an IShellFolder and an IShellView, but nothing seems to implement IShellItemFilter.

Seems like an XY problem you don't need this to enumerate a shell folder (you don't even need IShellFolder with Windows > Vista). You should describe what's exactly your initial problem.

You provide the IShellItemFilter. The system calls the GetEnumFlagsForItem method on the IShellItemFilter you provided.
